# How to read SPI values from MCP3202 on raspberry pi 3b+?

Tags: python, arm, raspberry-pi3, spi, microchip

I am trying to program raspberry pi 3 to read spi values from the ADC (mcp3202)

I referred to this

> https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/python-programming-tutorial-getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi/experiment-3-spi-and-analog-input

but the tutorial used [mcp3002 10bit ADC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTiqq.png) which is different from this [**mcp3202 12bit ADC**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nnir.png) which i am trying to implement

So what changes do I need to make in this

```
def read_adc(adc_ch, vref = 3.3):

    # Make sure ADC channel is 0 or 1
    if adc_ch != 0:
        adc_ch = 1

    # Construct SPI message
    #  First bit (Start): Logic high (1)
    #  Second bit (SGL/DIFF): 1 to select single mode
    #  Third bit (ODD/SIGN): Select channel (0 or 1)
    #  Fourth bit (MSFB): 0 for LSB first
    #  Next 12 bits: 0 (don't care)
    msg = 0b11
    msg = ((msg << 1) + adc_ch) << 5
    msg = [msg, 0b00000000]
    reply = spi.xfer2(msg)

    # Construct single integer out of the reply (2 bytes)
    adc = 0
    for n in reply:
        adc = (adc << 8) + n

    # Last bit (0) is not part of ADC value, shift to remove it
    adc = adc >> 1

    # Calculate voltage form ADC value
    voltage = (vref * adc) / 1024

    return voltage
```

Comment: [Datasheet of MCP3002] (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21294C.pdf)

Comment: [Datasheet of MCP3202] (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21034d.pdf)

Comment: Here is in-kernel driver https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/adc/mcp320x.c and here is the user space library (Python bindings are there as well): https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio, I **do not** see any reason why not to use them.

Comment: I am new to linux, is there something you could point to, to help me use those python bindings

Comment: Above link to `libiio` wiki is quite good enough.

Comment: not able to use that

Comment: Then use **in-kernel** driver for whatever OS you have there.